# equation for a curve

Tags: math

can anybody help me with an equation for this curve?

http://temp.electrobeat.dk/eq.gif

```
I need to make an equation for an acceleration..
x = time
y = velocity (pixel)

constants:
t = time in ms when to recalculate the equation
m = max speed in pixels (y)
a = acceleration (how fast the curve rises)
```

EDIT:

I have found an equation here which works, but I can't figure out what each parameter is for?

```
Tween.regularEaseOut = function(t,b,c,d){
    return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
    }
```

Comment: This is inconsistent - is "y" representing "position", or "velocity"?

Comment: To match the original curve, just try `y = m * (1 - exp(-t * n))`.  Choice of `n` (which will be proportional to `a`) is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it :)

```
<div id="tst" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px; height:100px; width:100px; background:#ff0000"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Tween(){
        this.time = 0;
        this.begin = 200;
        this.change = 1000;
        this.duration = 800

        this.regularEaseInOut = function(t,b,c,d){
            if((t/=d/2) < 1){
                return c/2*t*t + b;
            }
            else{
                return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
            }
        };
    }
    var Tween = new Tween();

    var int = 10;
    var loop = setInterval(function(){
        Tween.time += int;
        if(Tween.time >= Tween.duration){
            clearInterval(loop);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('tst').style.left = Tween.regularEaseInOut(Tween.time, Tween.begin, Tween.change, Tween.duration)+'px';
        }
    }, int);
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to see a plot of that function to see whether it's remotely like the one you asked for.

Answer (score 4):

It looks very much like a standard 1/CR style capacitor charging curve from electronics, which from memory has an equation of:

```
 (1 - e^(-t/RC))
```

The factor "RC" (resistance * capacitance) controls how quickly the slope approaches the asymptote.

See e.g. http://jcsu.jesus.cam.ac.uk/~rpc25/notes/physics/capacitors/index.html

The shape of the curve comes from the fact that the *rate* of charge (i.e. the first derivative) is proportional to the *difference* between the current value and the target value.

Comment: yes, it could look like a 4-pole highpass filter.. if you know anything about music

Comment: @clarkk - I do, and it's not the right shape for a filter transfer curve.

Comment: no, but it looks like.. but can you explain more specifik how to understand the equation? to me it's just #!& :)

Comment: please add more detail to your question.